# R MLR package - Saving performance for each parameter

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

I am using the `mlr` package in R to run the KNN algorithm. I am using `tuneParams` to search for the optimal `k`. When I run `tuneParams` the output shows the performance for each value of `k`. How can I save the performance for each `k`? The `TuneResult` object only has the optimal performance. I would like to use this to create a graph with the performance as a function of `k`.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Please include your code.

Comment: I've tried using the ``sink`` function to save the output (which didn't work), but I was wondering if ``mlr`` stores it somewhere and I can access it.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using please?

Comment: I figured it out, you can use ``TuneResult$opt.path$env$path``

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer you found yourself:
The best way to access all the settings that have been tried out:

`as.data.frame(TuneResult$opt.path)`